# Installing GitLab and get it running on a subdomain

Tags: linux, git, centos, gitlab

I am struggling to find a proper solution to this. So, well, I have a dedicated server with Hostgator running Cent OS. I have followed the instructions [here](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/) and done the following things:

```
curl -O https://downloads-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/centos-6.6/gitlab-7.6.2_omnibus.5.3.0.ci.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
sudo yum install openssh-server
sudo yum install postfix
sudo yum install cronie
sudo service postfix start
sudo chkconfig postfix on
sudo rpm -i gitlab-7.6.2_omnibus.5.3.0.ci.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

I have done all of this things in my root directory. Now, this might seem a very stupid question, but what I am trying to understand is 2 things:

1. How do I access the front-end? On what url by default it should be available?
2. Would it be possible to get it up on sub-domain?

I have followed many links but didn't clearly understand any of those, just adding a few links from SO for reference:

1. [How to configure GitLab as a subdomain in nginix.conf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240217/how-to-configure-gitlab-as-a-subdomain-in-nginix-conf)
2. [How to change URL of a working GitLab install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456129/how-to-change-url-of-a-working-gitlab-install)
3. [Install GitLab on Subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27012226/install-gitlab-on-subdomain)

Now, this could be a very simple question, but I believe I am struggling with the basics here and any help here would be really appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You are using the omnibus package which means the configuration is in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`. Read the [documentation](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md) if you haven't done already. For the subdomain check the [nginx section](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/nginx.md).

Comment: Yes, I have read the documentation, as mentioned in the documentation, it should be available "over HTTP at the IP or hostname of your server", but it is not, also, I already have a website running on that IP, so that won't be a good solution, further as mentioned in my question, I have tried multiple solutions, also added references, one of the includes changing etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb with no success.. request you to go through the question again, thanks :)

Comment: Ok you didn't mention that you host another site under the same server. In that case you should use the external web server as stated in [docs](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/nginx.md#using-a-non-bundled-web-server).

Comment: I am sorry, I am still not able to get any closer (probably I am missing something), the link you mentioned, just suggests using non'-ngnix server (apache in this case)..however, still the question holds. It would be really nice of you if you could script down a proper answer. Thanks.